# Is it possible to debug flash cs4 project inside flash builder?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript

I am debugging both a flash cs4 project and a flash builder project, actually the flash builder project will load the flash cs4 project thru swfloader, but the system can only support one debugger at a time. So I am seeking a method to debug it simultaneously...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try using [De MonsterDebugger](http://demonsterdebugger.com/) or [Alcon Debugger](http://blog.hexagonstar.com/alcon/).